# Is this set empty?

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, diophantine-equations, lattices, vector-spaces

Suppose we have two rank $n-1$ matrices in $\Bbb Z^{(n-1)\times n}$ given by
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
c_{1}&  -d_{1}&    0&     0&\dots 0&   0\\
0&    c_{2}&  -d_{2}&     0&\dots 0&   0\\
0&     0&   c_{3}&   -d_{3}&\dots 0&   0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&     0&   0&    0&\dots c_{n-1}&  -d_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
e_{1}&  -f_{1}&    0&     0&\dots 0&   0\\
0&    e_{2}&  -f_{2}&     0&\dots 0&   0\\
0&     0&   e_{3}&   -f_{3}&\dots 0&   0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&     0&   0&    0&\dots e_{n-1}&  -f_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where assume each $|c_i|>T,|d_j|>T,|e_k|>T^2,|f_l|>T^2$ and $(c_i,d_i)=(e_i,f_i)=1$ and $(c_1d_1\dots c_{n-1}d_{n-1},e_1f_1\dots e_{n-1}f_{n-1})=1$ holds.

Consider the row space $\mathcal C\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ of $C$ and row space $\mathcal D\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ of $D$ (linear combination of rows).

Consider $\mathcal L_\Bbb Z=\mathcal C\cap\mathcal D\cap\Bbb Z^n$ and let $\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star=\mathcal L_\Bbb Z\backslash(0,\dots,0)$.

Is it true that for any vector $(v_1,\dots,v_n)\in\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star$ there is an $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $|v_i|>T^2$?

---

If rows of $C$ are $u_i$ and rows of $D$ are $w_i$ and if every integer vector in intersection of space spanned by $C$ and $D$ is given by

$$a_1u_1+....+a_{n-1} u_{n-1}=b_1w_1+....+b_{n-1} w_{n-1}$$

where $a_i,b_j$ are integers then at least one coordinate of vectors in intersection is $>T^2$ is true.

(Proof: $a_1=0 \iff b_1=0$ and so assume WLOG $a_1b_1\neq0$ then $a_1c_1=e_1b_1$ but since $gcd(c_1,e_1)=1$ therefore this first coordinate has to be bigger than $T^2$ and one can proceed inductively if $a_1=b_1=0$ holds).

However it is possible $a_i,b_j\in\Bbb R$ for some point $p\in\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star$. So the proof is incomplete

---

In general the space $\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star$ consists of vectors of form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1c_1\\
-a_1d_1+a_2c_2\\
-a_2d_2+a_3c_3\\
\vdots\\
-a_{n-2}d_{n-2}+a_{n-1}c_{n-1}\\
-a_{n-1}d_{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1e_1\\
-b_1f_1+b_2e_2\\
-b_2f_2+b_3e_3\\
\vdots\\
-b_{n-2}f_{n-2}+b_{n-1}e_{n-1}\\
-b_{n-1}f_{n-1}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Any assignment of $a_i,b_j$ has to satisfy all these equations and make all coordinates in both vectors integers.

a. We can set this up as a homogeneous linear system with $n-1$ equations and $2(n-1)$ unknowns $a_i,b_j$. So set of $a_i,b_j$ form a dimension $n-1$ subspace in $\Bbb R^{2(n-1)}$. However I cannot show a single integer point exists in $\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star$.

b. The condition on $a_1c_1,b_1e_1\in\Bbb Z$ forces $a_2,b_2$ to be particular values which forces $a_3,b_3$ and so on until $a_{n-1},b_{n-1}$. Now $a_{n-1},b_{n-1}$ each have two conditions - one coming from $a_{n-2},b_{n-2}$ and other coming from $a_{n-1}d_{n-1},b_{n-1}f_{n-1}\in\Bbb Z$ both of which I think would made denominator of $a_{n-1},b_{n-1}$ to be $1$ with at least probability $1$ and for this last coordinate the proof just provided should work.

---

I still think $\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star\neq\emptyset$.

However can following hold?

1. Given any vector $(v_1,\dots,v_n)\in\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star$ there is an $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $|v_i|>T^2$.

---

The consequence is that some pairs of linear diophantine equations under some $1$-norm constraint can be shown to have unique non-negative solutions. That is why this is important to me.

Comment: What is $T$? Should it be the same for all $n$? i.e.: you want to know that there is some $T$ such that the staement holds for all $n$, or that for each $n$ there is a $T_n$ such that the stament holds?

Comment: Your idea of finding the intersection of $\mathcal C \cap \mathcal D$ by solving equations applies in any field that contains the coefficients, in particular over $\mathbb Q$, i.e.: there is linear space over $\mathbb Q$, of dimension (as vector space over $\mathbb Q$) $ \ge 2(n-1)-n = n - 2$ (assume $n > 2$). So  $\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @VictorZurkowski I know there are rational points. I cannot see any norm properties of integer points though. I think there are integer points. However could the $1$-norm be above $T^2$ for any integer point? That seems definitely possible given from the integer coordinate argument.

Comment: I am stil not sure what the role of $T$ is, but certainly, if $(v_1,\dots,v_n)\in\mathcal L_\Bbb Z^\star$, then trivially for some $i$, $|v_i| \ge 1$. This trivial fact does not use any information from $C, D$. I suppose this is not what you want, that is why I asked about $T$.

Comment: @VictorZurkowski  $T$ controls the coefficients of the matrix and therefore hypothetically controls the $1$-norm of any integer point in the intersection space. If you look at my argument $T$ is independent of $n$ and even if $T$ depends on $n$ I doubt if the dependence is more than logarithmic factors.